# How to find taxonomy parent id from child taxonomy page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

This site is in beta at: beta2.dixiestarkhome.com , the page for context is: http://beta2.dixiestarkhome.com/taxon/upholstery/sofas-settees/

my custom taxonomy is "taxon", sofas is a child of upholstery.

I want to find the parent taxon, and then do a wp_list_categories on that parent.

This is the code that runs the taxon listing:

```
<div id="nav" class="bottom-border">
 <?php 
//list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

$taxonomy     = 'taxon';
$orderby      = 'name'; 
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title,
  'depth'        => '1'
);
?>

<ul class="navigation-list">
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>


 <?php 
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
//list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)
$args2 = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title,
  'depth'        => '1',
  'child_of'     => $term->term_id

);
?>

<ul id="sub_nav">
<?php wp_list_categories( $args2 ); ?>
</ul>
```

If I am on the Uphostery page it works fine and shows the children.  If I am on the sofa's page it just says "No Categories"

To recap, I need to find the taxon parent and then list the child taxons...

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer actually turned out to be incredibly simple. Since I was already:

```
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
```

I could simple do:

```
$term->parent
```

Comment: I would recommend `$term = get_queried_object();`.  Or, if you don't need the term for anything else: `$parent = get_queried_object()->parent;`.